# xslt xpath + multiple stylesheets problem

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm creating for school a multiple choice program. For this I have to write an xslt stylesheet to show the right answer.

My XML has the following strucure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE QUIZ SYSTEM "quiz.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="quizanswers.xsl"?>
<quiz>
<multipleChoice solution="3">
    <question>Question 1</question>
    <answer>answer 1</answer>
    <answer>answer 2</answer>
    <answer>answer 3</answer>
    <answer>answer 4</answer>
</multipleChoice>
<multipleChoice solution="4">
    <question>Question 1</question>
    <answer>answer 1</answer>
    <answer>answer 2</answer>
    <answer>answer 3</answer>
    <answer>answer 4</answer>
</multipleChoice>
</quiz>
```

With the following xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Answers</h1>
<xsl:for-each select="quiz/multipleChoice">
<u><br></br><xsl:value-of select="question"/></u><br></br>
- <xsl:value-of select="question[../multipleChoice/@solution]"/> <br />
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i want is to set the number from attribute solution in the question[attribute of solution]. Which I achieved but doesn't work. Has anyone a solution/suggestion for thi problem?

I also want to have this xml file to have multiple stylesheets... Is that possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just noticed that your root element `<quiz>` is lowercase, but your doctype declaration is uppercase (`QUIZ`). You should change your doctype to match the case of your root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Multiple stylesheets by including them as follows:

```
<xsl:include href="mutiple.xsl"/>
```

It looks like you should be wanting the answer and not the question? So your XSLT should be something like

**Final version**

After useful comments from DevNull I agree this is the cleanest solution

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Answers</h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="quiz/multipleChoice">
                <u>
                    <br></br>
                    <xsl:value-of select="question"/>
                </u>
                <br></br>
                <br />
                <xsl:value-of select="answer[number(../@solution)]" /><br />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think there are 2 issues with this answer. 1) `format-number()` returns a string so you're not going to get the return values you're expecting. 2) You need to get the @solution from the parent (multipleChoice). You're `select` should look like this: `select="answer[number(../@solution)]"`

Comment: Comment after update: I'd still go with your first stylesheet and modify your `select`. It's cleaner than creating a variable imo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Answers</h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="question">
  <u>
    <br />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </u>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="answer" />

<xsl:template match="answer[position() = ../@solution]">
  <xsl:text>- </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <br />
</xsl:template>
```

The last two templates ignore all answers, except where the position of the answer node (among answer nodes only) is equal to the @solution attribute of it's parent.